# How to override the __dir__ method for a class?

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming

I want to change the `dir()` output for my class. Normally, for all other objects, it's done by defining own `__dir__` method in their class. But if I do this for my class, it's not called.

```
class X(object):
    def __dir__():
        raise Exception("No!")

>>>dir(X)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',....
```

How can I change the `dir()` output for class?

Comment: See [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup); `type(X).__dir__` is used, not `X.__dir__`.

Comment: "Normally, for all other objects, it's done by defining own `__dir__` method in their class" - same with this object. You define a `__dir__` method in this class's class, a.k.a. its metaclass.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `dir` calls the `__dir__` of the type of the input (equivalent to: `type(inp).__dir__(inp)`). For instances of a class it will call the classes `__dir__` but if called on a class it will call the `__dir__` of the meta-class.

```
class X(object):
    def __dir__(self):  # missing self parameter
        raise Exception("No!")

dir(X())  # instance!
# Exception: No!
```

So if you want to customize `dir` for your class (not instances of your class) you need to add a metaclass for your `X`:

```
import six

class DirMeta(type):
    def __dir__(cls):
        raise Exception("No!")

@six.add_metaclass(DirMeta)
class X(object):
    pass

dir(X)
# Exception: No!
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But now I stuck inside `__dir__`, because in reality I don't want to `raise` anything, I just want to remove few methods (from unittest's inspection). But I couldn't find any way to get access to `cls` content. I knew, I shouldn't go into this forest...

Comment: Oh, I found `cls.__dict__.keys()`. Exactly what I need.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin The alternative would be to use the inheritance from `type`. For example using `normal_dir = super().__dir__()` (this is what would be normally shown when you call `dir`) and then modify (add/remove stuff) the `normal_dir` before returning it. But `cls.__dict__.keys()` should also work. :)

Answer (score 4):

As @MSeifert already explained, `dir` calls the `__dir__` attrbiute of the object's class. So `type(X).__dir__` is called, not `X.__dir__`. Just for those that are interested, here is a look behinds the scenes of what exactly occurs.

The implementation of `dir` is in [bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L778):

```c
builtin_dir(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *arg = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "dir", 0, 1, &arg))
        return NULL;
    return PyObject_Dir(arg);
}
```

The `dir` function calls the API function `PyObject_Dir`. The `PyObject_Dir` function is implemented in [object.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Objects/object.c#L1421):

```c
PyObject *
PyObject_Dir(PyObject *obj)
{
    return (obj == NULL) ? _dir_locals() : _dir_object(obj);
}
```

`PyObject_Dir` is defined using two helper functions. When an object is passed in - as is the case here - then the `_dir_object` function is called. It is also implemented in [object.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Objects/object.c#L1388):

```c
static PyObject *
_dir_object(PyObject *obj)
{
    PyObject *result, *sorted;
    PyObject *dirfunc = _PyObject_LookupSpecial(obj, &PyId___dir__);

    assert(obj);
    if (dirfunc == NULL) {
        if (!PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "object does not provide __dir__");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* use __dir__ */
    result = _PyObject_CallNoArg(dirfunc);
    Py_DECREF(dirfunc);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* return sorted(result) */
    sorted = PySequence_List(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    if (sorted == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (PyList_Sort(sorted)) {
        Py_DECREF(sorted);
        return NULL;
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

The part were focusing on is:

```
PyObject *dirfunc = _PyObject_LookupSpecial(obj, &PyId___dir__);
```

This is where the `__dir__` special method is looked-up on the object passed in. This is done using `_PyObject_LookupSpecial`. `_PyObject_LookupSpecial` is defined in [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e3b2b4b8d9e751b49e3550cb83ba39b54fdc377c/Objects/typeobject.c#L1418):

```c
PyObject *
_PyObject_LookupSpecial(PyObject *self, _Py_Identifier *attrid)
{
    PyObject *res;

    res = _PyType_LookupId(Py_TYPE(self), attrid);
    if (res != NULL) {
        descrgetfunc f;
        if ((f = Py_TYPE(res)->tp_descr_get) == NULL)
            Py_INCREF(res);
        else
            res = f(res, self, (PyObject *)(Py_TYPE(self)));
    }
    return res;
}
```

`_PyObject_LookupSpecial` first calls `Py_TYPE` on the object passed in, before looking-up the attribute using `_PyType_LookupId`. [`Py_TYPE` is a macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h#L118) that gets the `ob_type` member of objects. It's expanded form is:

```
(((PyObject*)(o))->ob_type)
```

And as you probably guessed, The [`ob_type` attribute is the class (or type) of the object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h#L112):

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

So, as you can see from above, the `__dir__` attribute used is indeed the object's class.